# Что делает if __name__ == “__main__”?

Tags: python

Что происходит во время вызова `if __name__ == "__main__":`?

```
# Threading example
import time, thread

def myfunction(string, sleeptime, lock, *args):
    while 1:
        lock.acquire()
        time.sleep(sleeptime)
        lock.release()
        time.sleep(sleeptime)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    lock = thread.allocate_lock()
    thread.start_new_thread(myfunction, ("Thread #: 1", 2, lock))
    thread.start_new_thread(myfunction, ("Thread #: 2", 2, lock))
```

<sub>Перевод вопроса «[What does `if __name__ == “__main__”` do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/)» [@Devoted](https://stackoverflow.com/users/51518/devoted).</sub>

Comment: ассоциация: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/

Answer (score 77, accepted):

Когда интерпретатор Python читает исходный файл, он исполняет весь найденный в нем код. Перед тем, как начать выполнять команды, он определяет несколько специальных переменных. Например, если интерпретатор запускает некоторый модуль (исходный файл) как основную программу, он присваивает специальной переменной `__name__` значение `"__main__"`.  Если этот файл импортируется из другого модуля, переменной `__name__` будет присвоено имя этого модуля.

В случае с вашим сценарием, предположим, что код исполняется как основная функция, например:

```
python threading_example.py
```

После задания специальный переменных интерпретатор выполнит инструкцию `import` и загрузит указанные модули. Затем он проанализирует блок `def`, создаст объект-функцию и переменную под названием `myfunction`, которая будет указывать на этот объект.

Затем он прочтет инструкцию `if`, «поймёт», что `__name__` эквивалентен `"__main__"`, и выполнит указанный блок.

Одна из причин делать именно так – тот факт, что иногда вы пишете модуль (файл с расширением `.py`), предназначенный для непосредственного исполнения. Кроме того, он также может быть импортирован и использован из другого модуля. Производя подобную проверку, вы можете сделать так, что код будет исполняться только при условии, что данный модуль запущен как программа, и запретить исполнять его, если его хотят импортировать и использовать функции модуля отдельно.

Дополнительно см. [эту страницу](http://ibiblio.org/g2swap/byteofpython/read/module-name.html).

**Что означает "threading_example в данный момент импортируется из другого модуля"?**

Это означает, что кем-то в каком-либо файле `.py` (или в ходе интерактивной Python-сессии) используется выражение `import threading_example`. Противоположный этому случай – пользователь использует выражение `python threading_example.py` или `./threading_example.py`, и т. д.  В последнем случае, `threading_example.py` запущен как основная программа.  В первом же случае он запущен как-то иначе (чтобы понять, ищите вызов вида `import threading_example`).

<sub>Перевод ответа «[What does `if __name__ == “__main__”` do?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/419185/564240)» [@Mr Fooz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/25050/mr-fooz).</sub>

Comment: Хорошее объяснение.

Answer (score 2):

Во время вызова `if __name__ == "__main__"`: выполняется проверка, запущен ли скрипт напрямую или импортирован из другого модуля. Если скрипт запущен напрямую, то значение переменной `__name__` устанавливается в `"__main__"`, что позволяет выполнить код внутри блока `if`. Если скрипт импортирован из другого модуля, то значение `__name__` устанавливается в имя модуля, и код внутри блока `if` не выполняется.

Часто `if __name__ == "__main__"`: используется в скриптах, чтобы обеспечить, что определенный код выполняется только при запуске скрипта, а не при импортировании скрипта в другой модуль. Это может быть полезно, например, если у вас есть скрипт, который содержит функции, которые могут быть использованы в других модулях, но также содержит код, который должен выполняться только при запуске скрипта. В этом случае, код, который должен выполняться только при запуске скрипта, может быть помещен внутри блока if.

Например, в приведенном вами коде `if __name__ == "__main__"`: используется для того, чтобы убедиться, что функция `thread.start_new_thread()` вызывается только при запуске скрипта, а не при импортировании скрипта в другой модуль.

Есть несколько способов использовать `if __name__ == "__main__"`. Например, вы можете использовать этот код для запуска тестов или для запуска приложения с определенными начальными параметрами.

Например:

```
def main():
    # Code to run when the script is executed directly
    print("Hello, world!")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

В этом примере функция `main()` будет вызвана только при запуске скрипта, а не при импортировании скрипта в другой модуль. Это может быть полезно, например, если вы хотите, чтобы функция `main()` выполнялась только при запуске скрипта, а не при импортировании скрипта в другой модуль.

Вы также можете использовать `if __name__ == "__main__"`: для запуска тестов. Например:

```
def test_example():
    # Code for running tests
    assert 1 + 1 == 2

if __name__ == "__main__":
    test_example()
```

В этом примере функция `test_example()` будет вызвана только при запуске скрипта

Вы также можете использовать `if __name__ == "__main__"`: для запуска приложения с определенными начальными параметрами. Например:

```
def run_application(parameter):
    # Code for running the application
    print("Running application with parameter:", parameter)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    if len(sys.argv) > 1:
        parameter = sys.argv[1]
    else:
        parameter = "default"
    run_application(parameter)
```

В этом примере функция `run_application()` будет вызвана только при запуске скрипта, а не при импортировании скрипта в другой модуль. Кроме того, при запуске скрипта с параметром командной строки (например, python `script.py parameter`), этот параметр будет использован в качестве параметра для функции `run_application()`. Если параметр командной строки не указан, то будет использован значение по умолчанию (`"default"`).