# Объясните код if __name__ == "__main__" в терминах языка Java

Tags: java, python

Я новичок в Python и стараюсь понять все через язык, который знаю, - через Java. Наткнувшись на `if __name__ == "__main__"`, впал в ступор. Читаю ответы по данной теме, но все равно инфа сложно "ложится". Есть ли аналог этих `__name__` да `"__main__"` на языке Java? Заранее спасибо.

P.S. Не нужно писать про дубликат. В вопросах нет аналогов с Java. Не стоит рубить с плеча. Прочтите мой вопрос внимательно, пожалуйста.

Comment: Похожий вопрос [что делает if __name__ == "__main__"](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/515852/255866)

Comment: Там нет аналогов с Java. Не стоит рубить с плеча. Прочтите мой вопрос внимательно, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

По отдельности эти конструкции на Java не перевести, но вместе - вполне возможно если понимать что они делают.

Дело в том, что в Питоне любой модуль является исполнимым - и если его запустить, он всегда получает имя `__main__`. Ну а `__name__` - это имя текущего модуля. Таким образом, проверка `if __name__ == "__main__"` проверяет что модуль был запущен из командной строки, а не был импортирован из другого модуля.

Иными словами, проверка `if __name__ == "__main__"` - это дополнительная **точка входа в программу**.

В языке Java точками входа в программу являются методы main:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
```

Comment: Спасибо) Так понятнее.

Answer (score 7):

Подробный ответ на то, что делает эта констнукция в Python, есть по [ссылке](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/515852/255866), приведённой пользователем Twiss в комментарии, перепечатывать я это не буду.

В Java аналога такой конструкции нет и быть не может. В отличии от Python, импорт класса в Java не выполняет весь его код автоматически, поэтому подобные костыли не нужны. Кроме того, в Java программу нельзя начинать выполнять с произвольного класса. Точкой входа в программу может быть только класс, в котором есть метод с сигнатурой

```
public static void main(String[] args)
```

Если попытаться запустить класс, в котором такого метода нет, то вылетит ошибка "Main method not found".