# Почему не работает функция!

Tags: python

Помогите нубу! :) Почему так работает:

```
import requests
token = '&oauth_token=AQAAAAANPf09AAT6g_R0w6RqVU0rnJhZ_wpH6m0'
id = '&id=39666210'
url = "https://api-metrika.yandex.ru/stat/v1/data?preset=sources_summary"
r = requests.get(url+id+token)
res = r.json()
print(res)
```

а так нет:

```
import requests
def main():
    token = '&oauth_token=AQAA666NPf09AAT6g_R0w6RqVU0rnJhZ_wpH6m0'
    id = '&id=77666210'
    url = "https://api-metrika.yandex.ru/stat/v1/datapreset=sources_summary"
    r = requests.get(url+id+token)
    res = r.json()
    print(res)
```

* токен и id изменены)

Comment: Потому что мало просто определить функцию, надо ее еще и вызвать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Просто вызови созданную функцию после ее определения.

```
def main():
    print("blablabla")

main()
```

Answer (score 1):

Потому что не хватает конструкции в конце файла:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Подробнее про то, что эта конструкция значит, можно почитать в этом ответе:

[Что делают if __name__ == “__main__”?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/515852)