# Использование __name__

Tags: python, python-3.x

Объясните пожалуйста мне использование вот такого выражения: `if __name__ == '__main__'`. Я не могу понять где, для чего и когда может это применяться. Я новичок.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/515852/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%82-if-name-main

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Что делают if \_\_name\_\_ == “\_\_main\_\_”?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/515852/%d0%a7%d1%82%d0%be-%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%8e%d1%82-if-name-main)

Comment: Я читал данный вопрос, но я не понял почти всего что человек написал. Может кто-нибудь понятней объяснит, я имею ввиду как для новичка.

Comment: Ну в двух словах: `__name__` содержит "каким способом запущена прога" т.е "\_\_main\_\_" если вы просто запустили ее, а если нет, то вы импортировали ее как модуль. Так вот, `if __name__ == '__main__'` значит "Если программа именно запущена, а не импортирована:". Хотя вообще это используется для хорошего code-style.

Comment: Как понимать для хорошего code-style?

Comment: Грубо говоря значит сделать код легче читаемым, соответствующим "традициям" языка.

Comment: @VictorsaysReinstateMonica, это не имеет отношения к читаемости - слабо себе представляю как включение `if __name__ == '__main__'` в код хоть как-то может улучшить читаемость. Это чисто техническая штука.

Comment: @insolor Ну да, я не точно сказал.

Comment: В итоге я понял что это выражение необходимо только для проверки импорта т.е. импортирована программа в другую прогу, или запущена сама по себе? Правильно? И больше не для чего она не используется?

Comment: @Evgeniy, да, только для этого.