# Как работает метод main

Tags: java

Всем привет ребят, я прочитал в книге про метод `main`, как я понял это запуск/старт Java приложения, но я новичок и есть пару вопросов:

1. Как работают классы где нет метода `main`;
2. Как происходит взаимодействие других классов где нет метода `main` и я ещё видел приложение на Spring framework где в методе `main` вообще одна строка, но там же запускаются команды которые будут отрабатывать в приложении

Answer (score 2):

По пробую провести аналогию с реальным миром, возможно так будет понятней.

1. Метод main - это как дверной проем в квартиру, в которую вы хотите что то передать или забрать. А объекты классов - это все предметы в этой квартире, поэтому в каждом классе не требуется наличие дверного проема. Возвращаясь опять к практике, чтобы операционная система могла запустить процесс(программу), ей надо знать точный адрес дверного проема, это и есть main функция которая стандартизирована для исполняемых файлов и динамических библиотек. Очень часто присутвует в явном виде почти во всех языковых платформах, будь то Java, C#, C++, Python.

   Класс - это как лейкало для объектов, чтобы создать объект его надо проинициализировать, и после этого вы можете с ним выполнять любые операции которые позволяет этот класс, вызывая методы или обращаясь к полям. Зайдя в квартиру находим нужное лейкало, создаем себе объект и вуаля, делаем с ним что надо.
2. Например в случае с динамическими библиотеками, это дверь есть но она скрыта за кулисами, так как основная цель библиотеки переиспользовать классы, поэтому это квартира в которую передать ни чего нельзя но выносить можно. Что касается примера со Spring то не столь важно сколько строк в самой функции важно что при запуске процесса, main функция передаст управление во фреймворк, а феймворк проинициализирует необходимые вещи.

   Как если бы пришел человек из ростелекома провел вам кабель для интернета в квартиру, вы подключили к компьютеру и после этого можете получать сообщения от друзей. Операционная система при запуске процесса передала в main функцию все аргументы которые были указаны при запуске, например порт, а Spring начал слушать все сообщения на этом порту.

Надеюсь удалось прояснить ситуацию, а не еще больше запутать. С аналогиями всегда 50 на 50 шансы)

Comment: Хорошая аналогия, но про `Python` мимо, там есть `if __name__ == '__main__':`, но это нужно только для того, что ограничить код при импортировании скрипта в другой -- в этот момент будет выполняться код. Поэтому, нет в питоне аналога `main` функции

Comment: https://realpython.com/python-main-function/#a-basic-python-main вроде есть и также называют и выглядит похоже и принцип использования схожий, стоит еще передать `sys.argv` будет один в один. Просто в питоне смешали два в одно, и потому чтобы это как то различать необходимо проверять `__name__` чтобы понять что этот модуль был вызван как исполняемый, а не в результате импортирования. Просто немного под другим углом на это смотрю)

Comment: Неа, там по ссылке просто функция которую так назвали, она по умолчанию не становится точкой входа сама по себе, ее так сделал программист, вызвав в `if __name__ == '__main__':`, но это только для ограничения кода, чтобы не был выполнен код в этом условии при импортировании и всё -- https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/515853/201445 . Берем, c++, в нем точка входа кода в функции `main` у питона код **всегда** выполняется с первой строчки скрипта (с самого верха) и при импортировании скриптов, у них тоже выполняется код с первой строки их файлов

Comment: @gil9red естественно)