# Не запускается тест в питоне

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import unittest
from number_writer import get_formatted_name 

class NamesTestCase(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_first_last_name(self):
        formatted_name = get_formatted_name('janis', 'joplin')
        self.assertEqual(formatted_name, 'Janis', 'Joplin')

unittest.main()
```

Почему вместо запуска теста, импортируется и запускается программа

Импортирую этот код:

```
def get_formatted_name(first, last):
    full_name = first + ' ' + last
    return full_name.title()

print("Enter 'q' at any time to quit")
while True:
    first = input("\nplease give me a first name: ")
    if first == 'q':
        break
    last = input("\nplease give me a last name: ")
    if last == 'q':
        break

    formatted_name = get_formatted_name(first, last)
    print("\nNeatly formatted name: " + formatted_name)
```

Comment: Извини, а можно подробнее, я только начинаю кодить и поэтому не понимю

Answer (score 1):

При импорте модуля весь код, который находится не внутри функций или методов классов, запускается. Чтобы избежать запуска кода при импорте, его убирают в блок `if __name__ == “__main__”` (смысл проверки в том, что при импорте модуля глобальная переменная `__name__` равна имени этого модуля, а при запуске модуля без импорта она равна `"__main__"`).

Подробнее можно почитать в этом ответе: [Что делает `if __name__ == “__main__”?`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/515853/1365)

У вас при импорте модуля сразу запускается бесконечный цикл запроса данных от пользователя, до выполнения теста код не доходит. Нужно спрятать этот цикл в блок `if __name__ == “__main__”`, пример:

```
def get_formatted_name(first, last):
    full_name = first + ' ' + last
    return full_name.title()


def main():
    print("Enter 'q' at any time to quit")
    while True:
        first = input("\nplease give me a first name: ")
        if first == 'q':
            break
        last = input("\nplease give me a last name: ")
        if last == 'q':
            break

        formatted_name = get_formatted_name(first, last)
        print("\nNeatly formatted name: " + formatted_name)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Я обычно большие блоки (больше 1-2 строк) убираю в функцию с именем `main`, но это не обязательно, так тоже будет работать:

```
def get_formatted_name(first, last):
    full_name = first + ' ' + last
    return full_name.title()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Enter 'q' at any time to quit")
    while True:
        first = input("\nplease give me a first name: ")
        if first == 'q':
            break
        last = input("\nplease give me a last name: ")
        if last == 'q':
            break

        formatted_name = get_formatted_name(first, last)
        print("\nNeatly formatted name: " + formatted_name)
```

Comment: А теперь новая проблема, запускаю тест и ничего не происходит

Comment: @АлексейКарнеенко значит что-то не так запускаете, у меня ваш тест успешно падает) https://i.stack.imgur.com/ujcmQ.png

Comment: Блин, он не должен падать

Comment: Ну, функция возвращает 'Janis Joplin', а вы в тесте пишете, что должно возвращать 'Janis'. Если изменить на `self.assertEqual(formatted_name, 'Janis Joplin')`, то успешно проходит тест

Comment: Вот это выражение `self.assertEqual(formatted_name, 'Janis', 'Joplin')` означает, что formatted_name должно быть равно 'Janis', а если не равно, то нужно вывести сообщение 'Joplin'