Как отобразить число из базы данных?
import flet as ft
import sqlite3

db = sqlite3.connect('data_of_num.db')

c = db.cursor()

qwe = 0

c.execute("""CREATE TABLE num (
          number integer     
)""")

def main(page: ft.Page):
    page.title = 'my mini app'
    page.theme_mode = 'light'
    page.vertical_alignment = ft.MainAxisAlignment.CENTER
    page.window_width = 250
    page.window_height = 150
    page.window_resizable = False


    tex = ft.Text('', height= 20)   
    num = ft.TextField(value = '', width= 100, height= 35)


    def get_info(e):
        tex.value = num.value
        qwe = num.value
        c.execute(f"INSERT INTO num VALUES ({qwe})")
        page.update()

    add = ft.OutlinedButton(text='add', width=100, height=25, on_click = get_info)

    panel =  ft.Row(
            [
                ft.Column(
                    [ 
                        tex,
                        num,
                        add
                    ]
                )
            ],
            alignment=ft.MainAxisAlignment.CENTER
    )
    
    page.add(panel)
 
db.commit()
db.close()
ft.app(target=main)

мне нужно написать программу, где есть поле для ввода, куда можно ввести число, и кнопка, по нажатию которой, число которое я ввел, отобразилось выше этого поля
и потом даже после перезапуска программы, это число оставалось рядом с полем для ввода, и опять после ввода нового числа, это новое число заменило старое, и не исчезало после перезапуска.
вот я решил сохранять число которое ввел, в базу данных, а потом дописать функцию, что бы из базы данных забирать это число и вставлять рядом с полем для ввода, но я столкнулся с проблемой, что после запуска программы, и после ввода числа, оно не сохраняется в базу данных, и выдаёт ошибку:
sqlite3.ProgrammingError: SQLite objects created in a thread can only be used in that same thread.
The object was created in thread id 7252 and this is thread id 15008.

UPD CODE:
import flet as ft
import sqlite3

if __name__ == "__main__":
    db = sqlite3.connect('data_of_num.db')
    c = db.cursor()
    c.execute("""CREATE TABLE num (number integer)""")
    c.execute("INSERT INTO num VALUES(123)")
    db.commit()
    c.close()
    db.close()

def main(page: ft.Page):
    page.title = 'my mini app'
    page.theme_mode = 'light'
    page.vertical_alignment = ft.MainAxisAlignment.CENTER
    page.window_width = 250
    page.window_height = 150
    page.window_resizable = False

    db = sqlite3.connect('data_of_num.db')
    c = db.cursor()
    num_int = c.execute("SELECT number FROM num")
    tex = ft.Text(f'{num_int}', height= 20)   
    db.commit()
    c.close()
    db.close()
    num = ft.TextField(value = '', width= 100, height= 35)


    def get_info(e):
        tex.value = num.value
        page.update()

    add = ft.OutlinedButton(text='add', width=100, height=25, on_click = get_info)

    panel =  ft.Row(
            [
                ft.Column(
                    [ 
                        tex,
                        num,
                        add
                    ]
                )
            ],
            alignment=ft.MainAxisAlignment.CENTER
    )
    
    page.add(panel)
 
ft.app(target=main)


Курсор открывай в той же функции в которой делаешь запрос и там же закрывай его.

можете пожалуйста по подробнее рассказать, как я могу решить эту проблему?

Я начал изучать sqlite3 только позавчера, и еще довольно плох в нем, и в принципе только недавно начал изучать программирование, поэтому не очень понимаю как мне исправить эту ошибку. Я так понял я должен переставить c = db.cursor() в начало моей функции, но эта проблема не пропала. и как мне закрыть курсор? буду очень признателен за вашу помощь

тут ещё и инъекция sql...

Везде где делаете c.execute прямо перед этим делайте c = db.cursor(), а после этого c.close(). Это для начала.

я перед c.execute поставил везде db.cursor(), а после c.close(), как вы и сказали, что дальше?

Ошибка с другим тредом должна уйти по идее )  Хотя может и db.commit() придётся там же ставить

А ещё вот это почитайте про передачу параметров https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1374687/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b4%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bb%d1%8f%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b2-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b9-%d0%b2-sql-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%80

спасибо за статью, полезная, понял что за sql инъекция. однако, та ошибка не пропала, и еще в консоли теперь жалуется на c = db.cursor() в функции get_info()

Да, ещё поскольку у вас многопоточное приложение вам лучше защитить "бесхозный" код, находящийся вне функций через if __name__ == "__main__": Тут вот описано, хотя про многопоточность и не сказано: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/515852/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-if-name-main

получается все что находиться вне функций, лучше будет поставить в if name == "main":

но как же мне избавиться от ошибки?

все, я понял свою ошибку, я вместо того что бы закрывать курсор, случайно закрывал db = sqlite3.connect('data_of_num.db') . я сделал так, что бы с начало перед execute открывался курсор и коннект, а после закрывался, и теперь этой ошибки нет. однако теперь есть другой вопрос, я вот поместил в свою базу данных число 123, и при перезапуске и поля для ввода у меня не это число, а надпись <sqlite3.Cursor object at 0x00000214F0D3AC0>, как сделать так, что бы там было именно это число?  (сейчас обновлю сверху код)

number = c.fetchone()[0]

Думаю вопрос всё-равно в итоге закроют, потому что вы спрашиваете базовые вещи, которые много раз обсуждались уже в других вопросах. Вам бы нужно воспользоваться поиском тут и посмотреть примеры кода для работы с базой. Ну и таториалы по работе с БД на питоне почитать.

понятно, спасибо вам большое! вы мне очень помогли, и вопросов больше нет
